# Formatting a date in PHPExcel that can be updated after XLS is generated

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm try to output a date using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) where the format can be changed after generating the file.

So for example, I output the date, like this:

23/04/1989

And I can then format the cells, change the format and it shows something like:

April 23rd 1989

I've tried this approach (using the code below) and generated a file. When I click on the date cell and try to format it, it appears to have worked since it has the 'Date' category highlighted and the correct 'Type'.

[image]

However, if I change the format and click OK, the cell doesn't change it's format.

Here's my code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '23/04/1989');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);
```

Is this a limitation in Excel or am I not going about this the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert your date to an Excel serialized date/time stamp, and store that in the cell

```
$dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( strtotime('23-Apr-1989') );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', $dateValue);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);
```

Note that `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` accepts a unix timestamp or a DateTime object

```
$dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( 
    DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/04/1989') 
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', $dateValue);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);
```

And as your date of `23/04/1989` would be treated as `m/d/Y` by PHP (and therefore not what you'd expected - see PHP's [accepted format rules](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)) using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` allows you to specify that it's `d/m/Y`

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I also had to change the `setCellValueExplicit` function to `setCellValue` for it to work :)

Comment: This is strange. Using the above code I am getting 22-Apr-1989 showing up in Excel. In fact whatever date I put in it reduces it by one day. Other than that it works perfectly.

Comment: Ahh your second piece of code works perfectly, but the first one gets the date wrong in excel for some reason.

Comment: Probably a timezone issue... PHPExcel assumes UTC